# C, gcc error compiling simple program

Tags: c, gcc

I have some issues when I try to compile my very simple C game..

It says:

"line 125 error: expected identifier or '(' before 'return'
  return 0;"

and

"line 126 error: expected identifier or '(' before '}' token
 }"

(line 125 and 126 are the 2 last lines in my code)

```
<#include <stdio.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>



    int main (void)

    {

        int headbang,x,y,fx,fy;
        char choice;

        headbang = 0;



    {
     srand(1); 
     int fx = rand()%5 + 1; 
    }
     {
     srand(2); 
     int fy = rand()%5 + 1; 
    }
     {
     srand(3); 
     int x= rand()%5 + 1; 
     }
     {
     srand(4); 
     int y= rand()%5 + 1; 
     }


        printf ("It is pitch black. You have no idea how you got here, but you \nknow that you have to find some source of light in order to get \nout. \n \n");



        printf ("Where do you want to go? ");


        {
        scanf(" %c", &choice);


        switch (choice) 
    {
        case 'n':
    x++;

    printf ("You crawl North.\n");
    break;



        case 's':
    x--;

    printf("You crawl South \n");


        case 'e':

    y++;

    printf ("You crawl East.\n");
    break;

        case 'w':


    y--;

    printf ("You crawl West.\n");
    break;

    default:
    printf ("Sorry, you can only go north, south, east or west.");


    }
        if (x==0 || y==0 || x==6 || y==6)
    {
    printf("Ouch! You hit your head in the wall.");
    headbang++;

        if (x==0)
    {
    x++;
    }

        else if (y==0)
    {
    y++;
    }

        else if (x==6)
    {
    x--;
    }

        else if (y==6)
    {
    y--;
    }

    }

        if (headbang == 2)
    {
    printf ("You slip into a deep sleep, never to wake up again...");
    }

        if (x==fx && y==fy)
    {
    printf("You feel something on the floor. It is a flashlight! \n You wake up, finding yourself in your own bed. What a nightmare!");
    break;
    }


    while (!(x==fx && y==fy));  
    }
    }   
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Here's a BIG tip: don't ever write that much code before compiling. Learn to write a little piece of code and then test it before moving on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should put the return before the second to last `}` and remove the last bracket

Comment: Have an upvote for spotting that in this terribly formatted post ;)